# Why grafana graphic is not visible?

Tags: grafana

I have installed `Node eporter full` (1860) Grafana dashboard. It seems works, but CPU graphic is not visible:

[image]

[image]

As we can see, that values seems available. `CPU Busy` metric is working.

Why `CPU` percentage and `CPU Basic` graphs does not show graphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I solved it with the following steps:

1. By clicking on the title bar "CPU Basic" of the graph it will open a menu. Select "Edit".
2. At the top of the right sight you will see a drop down box showing the text "Time series". Click on that text.
3. Now you will see a list of possible graph types. Directly beyond the drop down box you will also see the button "Suggestions". Click on that button.
4. I've choosen the first suggestion.
5. After clicking on the blue button "Apply" you will the graph on the main page of the dashboard.

Hope that hepls.

Comment: That's the quick answer I needed ;)

Comment: Hi, may you please advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74335393/4632019): data graph is not rendered on different scale.