# Why grafana does not show data in different scale?

Tags: grafana

I have a graph. Data is displayed for 24h period, but when I change scale to 12h period, then data is not rendered.

Graphs examples:
[image]
[image]

Details are [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/57995)

Why `gitlab` data is not rendered on small scale?